# I'm not able to connect sftp using expect script

Tags: linux, expect

I'm not able to identify where I'm doing wrong.Please let me know if I'm doing wrong.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

File_Sftp ()
{
    set user="xxxx"
    set password="xxxxx"
    set host="ftp.xxxx.xxxx.com"

    STATUS=$(
    expect << EOF
    spawn sftp $user@$host
    expect "User Name:"
    send "$user\r"
    expect "Password:"
    send "$password\r"
    expect "sftp> "
    send "cd in\r"
    expect "sftp> "
    send "get $1\r"
    expect "sftp> "
    send "exit\r"
EOF
    )

    if [ "$(echo $STATUS | grep -c 226)" -ge 1 ]; then
      echo "Success";
    else
      echo "Unsuccessful" ;
    fi
}

File_Sftp "/usr/local/bin/xxxxxx.txt"
```

Whenever I'm trying to execute above shell script I got below error:

```
send: spawn id exp4 not open
    while executing
"send "\r""
Unsuccessful
```

Comment: Is it possible the cert is asking for an update? I always like to expect in the `USER@SERVER's password:` format as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These bash lines don't do what you think:

```
set user="xxxx"
set password="xxxxx"
set host="ftp.xxxx.xxxx.com"
```

They are not setting variable values, they are setting the positional parameter `$1` to the given string. The actual variables are **still unset**.

`spawn` would have failed trying to launch `sftp $user@$host` (actually `sftp @` with the unset variables), the `expect "User Name:"` would have timed out after the default 10 seconds, and then the error message comes from `send "$user\r"` (or `send "\r"` with the unset variables) -- no spawned process to interact with.

You can see this if you use `expect -d <<EOF` while testing (turning on expect's verbose debugging output)

You want

```
user="xxxx"
password="xxxxx"
host="ftp.xxxx.xxxx.com"
```

or, since this is bash, and we want to promote good programming practices (no global variables)

```
local user="xxxx"
local password="xxxxx"
local host="ftp.xxxx.xxxx.com"
```

---

Add an `expect eof` after sending "exit"

---

To see if `226` appears in expect's output, I would change this

```
if [ "$(echo $STATUS | grep -c 226)" -ge 1 ]; then
```

to

```
if grep -q '\<226\>' <<< "$STATUS" ; then
```

or

```
if [[ $STATUS == *226* ]]; then
```